# ListView align text to right and left ANDROID

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make an product list that has the products name aligned to the right side of the list view with its price aligned to the right side.

I made a `String` array and spaced the items outs but the text does not align properly. Is there a better way to do this other than in a string array in the `String` XML?

Comment: I'm just making a string array with the product and price side by side in my XML my problem is that I want the product to align to the left of the list view and its corresponding price to the right

Comment: <item >Capicola                       6.45</item>
    <item >Turkey                         6.45</item>
    <item >Roast Beef                     6.45</item>
    <item >Ham                            6.45</item>
    <item >Steak                          6.45</item>
    sort of like this but in the list view the are aligned to the left with name and price next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem easily by using a custom adapter.
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: you make a layout with the textviews positioned where you want it.then inflate it with the custom adapter.[here is another tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)